Replacing Numerical Axis Ticks with Text Using LabelExpression in Altair
I am trying to replace some numerical labels on an Altair chart with strings from a list using the labelExpression in Altair 4, however it doesn't seem to be working; it removes the numerical labels but doesn't actually include the text.
source = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [0, 10, 20, 30, 0, 10, 20, 30, 0, 10, 20, 30],
    'y': [0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20],
    'z': [4, 8, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
})

labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']

alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
    x=alt.X('x:O'),
    y=alt.Y('y:O', axis=alt.Axis(
                labelExpr=f"['{labels[0]}', '{labels[1]}', '{labels[2]}'][datum.y - 1]",
                )
           ),
    color=alt.Color('z:Q')
)

The labels just don't appear. I don't have a ton of experience writing label expressions, so any help would be appreciated!

You're close. It is just the indexing that is wrong. Use datum.label (or datum.value) to refer to the current value on each tick. And note that y - 1 becomes [-1, 9, 19] which does not match any position in the list. So you could do:
labelExpr=f"['{labels[0]}', '{labels[1]}', '{labels[2]}'][datum.label / 10]",

Or define the labels as a dictionary so that you can skip the / 10 for the positional indexing.

Awesome Joel - works perfectly. Thank you!

If I wanted to generate the expression dynamically - for example if the chart had 4 lines and labels was ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], is there a way to do this without hard coding the label expression?

@Hambone_McKool I think you can use the string representation of the list f"{labels.__str__()}[datum.label / 10]
